# Good example codebase (opensource project) for learning integration testing?

Tags: integration-testing, end-to-end

I would like to learn more about automated integration testing / end-to-end testing, especially for web applications.

I am looking for a good codebase, which has nicely structured, efficient integration tests, with good test coverage, to look for examples, stylistic choices, etc.

Is there an open source project which has such a well-maintained test-suite? Which one would you recommend for reviewing and learning from?

Comment: Also see the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252550/are-there-any-java-open-source-projects-with-both-integration-and-unit-test-suit

Answer (score 1):

Check the Wikia app , they have well structured test suite with the Page Object Model.
Look at there Github Repository :https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests
There site is:http://www.wikia.com/fandom

Answer (score 0):

You should not judge the book by its cover but [zurmo CRM](http://zurmo.org) looks promising because they claim: "We use a test-driven methodology for building every part of the application."

Answer (score 0):

The entire CI pipeline for Wikipedia, is public. https://integration.wikimedia.org/

This includes the Jenkins instance that runs all the integration tests for the Mediawiki framework (the software that powers Wikipedia). https://integration.wikimedia.org/ci/

You can also see coverage reporting https://integration.wikimedia.org/cover/

As well as code review https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/q/status:open,n,z